# Complete a table of time-frequency by time series

Tags: r, time-series

Consider a table of time-frequency

```
2008-01-01 2008-01-03 2008-01-05 2008-01-06 2008-01-07 2008-01-08
         1          8          2          2          3          1
```

Note that 2008-01-02 and 2008-01-04 are lost.

The expected result looks like this:

```
2008-01-01 2008-01-02 2008-01-03 2008-01-04 2008-01-05 2008-01-06 2008-01-07 2008-01-08
         1          0          8          0          2          2          3          1
```

Or in the form of a date frame:

```
   Time    Frequency
2008-01-01    1
2008-01-02    0
2008-01-03    8
2008-01-04    0
2008-01-05    2
2008-01-06    2
2008-01-07    3
2008-01-08    1
```

Answer (score 2):

A better option would be to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified and then do the `table`

```
rndates <- range(dates)
table(factor(dates, levels = as.character(seq(rndates[1], rndates[2], by = "1 day"))))
#  2008-01-01 2008-01-02 2008-01-03 2008-01-04 2008-01-05 2008-01-06 2008-01-07 2008-01-08 
#        4          0          7          0          1          5          6          2
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dates <- sample(as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2008-01-03", "2008-01-05", 
    "2008-01-06", "2008-01-07", "2008-01-08")), 25, replace = TRUE)
```